# Does measure imply the existence of limit function?

Tags: real-analysis

I am reading a book and I don't quite understand some of the statements. It says "$\{u_n\}$ is a Cauchy sequence in the space $L^2(\mathbb{R}^d;|\xi|^{2s}d\xi)$. Because $|\xi|^{2s}d\xi$ is a measure so there is a function $f$ in $L^2(\mathbb{R}^d;|\xi|^{2s}d\xi)$such that $\{u_n\}$ converge to $f$ in $L^2(\mathbb{R}^d;|\xi|^{2s}d\xi)$". I don't know why this is true. Why $|\xi|^{2s}d\xi$ is a measure can imply the conclusion? Thanks for any hint!

I have a follow up question. We know $f\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^d;|\xi|^{2s}d\xi)$. Then why $f1_{B(0,1)}\in S'(\mathbb{R}^d)$, which is a tempered distribution?Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like the Riesz-Fischer theorem. Perhaps check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%E2%80%93Fischer_theorem

Comment: $L^2$ spaces are complete: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/L2-Space.html

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in a comment above: $L^2$ spaces are Hilbert spaces (for the inner product corresponding to the measure), and therefore complete: Cauchy sequences converge.